# Loop through multiple Active Directory Ou's in Powershell

Tags: powershell

How do you search multiple OU's in Active Directory. Say if there are 4 OU's for different users, and need to search only 3 of the 4.
Currently I am using the below to search one path, how would I expand that to search multiple OU's.

```
$OU='AD Path'
Get-ADUser -SearchBase $OU -Properties Lastlogondate -filter {lastlogondate -lt $DisableDays}
```

Comment: See also [Get-Aduser Effective Multi-OU Search](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/8354b35a-e4f8-428b-918f-a10ab3efa5d0/getaduser-effective-multiou-search)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like -searchbase takes `<string>`, so you would need to loop through OUs.

The following query would get users in each OU:

```
$OU=@('cn=users,dc=xyz,dc=com','ou=companyusers,dc=xyz,dc=com')
$ou | foreach { get-aduser -searchbase $_ ...}
```

Comment: Generate error of Get-ADUser : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'SearchBase'. Specified method is not supported.

Comment: @TG09, yeah I wrote it on top of my head but just had a chance to check the actual parameter type