# Powershell GET-ADuser with searchbase against multipe AD OU's

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to build a script to run that searches for AD user accounts that are configured for Password_not_required (544) and change them to password_req (512).

I cant quite figure out the section on the `SearchBase` as I want to limit the search to 2 OU's only, I have put these in a variable `$OU` and referenced it but the script fails.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
# log file
    if ($logfile -eq $null)
    {
      $logfile = "C:\test\ADUsersChangedPWNOTREQD.txt"
      New-Item $logfile -ItemType File
    }

#OU Information
    $ous = 'OU=Standard users,DC=x1,DC=contoso,DC=com','OU=Standard users,DC=x2,DC=contoso,DC=com'

# set flag PasswordNotRequired to false
    $UsersNoPwdRequired = Get-ADUser -Properties Name,distinguishedname,useraccountcontrol,objectClass -SearchBase $ous -LDAPFilter "(&(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=32)(!(|(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=65536)(IsCriticalSystemObject=TRUE))))"

    foreach($user in $UsersNoPwdRequired )
    {
      Set-ADAccountControl $user -PasswordNotRequired $false
      Add-Content $logfile "$User"
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loop through multiple Active Directory Ou's in Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24072966/loop-through-multiple-active-directory-ous-in-powershell)

Answer (score 3):

Just do:

```
$ous = 'OU=Standard users,DC=x1,DC=contoso,DC=com','OU=Standard users,DC=x2,DC=contoso,DC=com'

$ous | ForEach-Object {
    $UsersNoPwdRequired = Get-ADUser -Properties Name,distinguishedname,useraccountcontrol,objectClass -SearchBase $_ -LDAPFilter "(&(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=32)(!(|(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=65536)(IsCriticalSystemObject=TRUE))))"

    foreach($user in $UsersNoPwdRequired )
    {
        Set-ADAccountControl $user -PasswordNotRequired $false
        Add-Content $logfile "$User"
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah i was just giving him a quick answer to his solution, there are probably a ton of ways to do it better then this. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for the comments.  How can I run it efficiently as my user base is approx 40k.  when you say move the Get-ADUser section out of the For-Each loop, do you mean position it after the $ou variable and before the For-each bit?

Comment: @Bill_Stewart the `-SearchBase` parameter doesn't take multiple OUs though, if he moved the `$UsersNoPwdRequired = Get-ADUser ...` outside of the `ForEach-Object` block he wouldn't be able to loop through both OUs listed. Otherwise he would have to create two `Get-ADUser` lines, one for each OU.

Comment: @AlanBrooke user3304533 is correct; that's called "me not paying attention." I've deleted my comments; please disregard.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Guys, does the job, I will look to make it efficient by moving the Get-aduser out of the For-each loop when I get abit more time.